# Most effective lightsabre dual-wielder at low levels?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, optimization

It's been implied that my current Jedi character in SWSE might die/be handed in by the party, whilst the GM plays him as an NPC. In that eventuality I'd like to bring out another Jedi but focus on dual-wielding. However looking at the dual-wielding feats, this approach looks horribly ineffective. My character will be *level 5* when I bring them in, restricting them to just the first DW feat, with a massive -5 penalty. The second in the feat tree requires BAB=6, and thus is off-limits for level 5 .

Is using feats the only way to approach this build, or is there another avenue I can take?

Comment: Short version (not from experience, not really answer) http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75862/19423134/New_to_Saga_edition_(Char_Builds_help)&post_num=4#330257038 and basically indicate that rapid strike can make it *look* like you're attacking until you get Dual weapon handling up high enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Human with a [shoto](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showpost.php?p=8410694&postcount=9):

> another possibility (this is what one of my players did) is to get a standard lightsaber and a shoto then get the Shoto Focus talent (from jedi academy). So long as you wield both and just attack with the shoto you get +2 attack. Then you can build towards having the dual-weapon fighting feats to get more attacks. Feats-wise you can't go wrong with weapon focus (lightsabers). If you're going two-weapons then Dual-weapon fighting 1 is a good choice to build towards future feats, alternatively Force Training could be useful, especially with Battle Strike and a lightsaber form (I'd recommend twin strike if you're going with two weapons).

At low level, you'll mainly just be holding two light sabers. But with the build, you'll be attacking with shoto focus or a twin-striking lightsaber form.

Looking [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showpost.php?p=8422203&postcount=16):

You'll probably want to start multiclassed for skill versatility.

> Like everything, your build and powers depends on what you want to do. But in general, SWSE rewards multi-classing. Starting with Scout, Scoundrel, or Noble will give you much better starting skills and feats then a Jedi. Multiclassing gives you more Talents. And multiclassing lets you cherry pick the best Talents.
>
> A standard untouchable Jedi build goes something like Scout 1/Jedi 1-3/Scout 2-5/Scoundrel 1/Jedi Knight X/Jedi Master Y. This gives you Evasion, Uncanny Dodge, Fringe Savant (all Scout), Block, Deflect (Jedi), Fool's Luck (Scoundrel), Skill Focus Use the Force (feat), Soresu, Shii-Cho, (Lightsaber Forms, and yes, you can use more then one at a time) + Serenity (Jedi Master).
>
> Evasion + Uncanny Dodge + Block + Defense + lightsaber forms gives you untouchably strong defenses.

While the untouchable build is outside your nominal requirements, it does seem like an excellent thing to build towards at the early-game to allow you to survive to get the mid-game dual wielding feats.

Also, ewoks apparently make excellent dual wielders. Your chances of party-kill go up to 110% but... sacrifices must be made?

It looks like most of the options that you want are located in the Jedi Academy Training Manual. (Handy list of [lightsaber forms](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=84676))

Critically:

> Form VI: Niman
> You use a very general form that covers all the bases. This is the "jack-of-all-trades" style of lightsaber combat.
> Prerequisites: Wisdom 13. Form I: Shii-Cho. Weapon Proficiency(Lightsaber)
> Benefits: You gain a +1 bonus to Reflex, Will, and Fortitude Defense. You also gain an insight bonus to attack rolls equal to your Wisdom modifier.

This should allow you to overcome the penalties of dual-weapon fighting (to a playable degree at 1st) without an overly-onerous feat investment, especially with the Shoto (or ewok dual shotoing) design.

Of course... it seems that the above class is a houseruled class, so YMMV.

Looking [here](http://saga-edition.com/boards/topic.php?id=1666) we again see reference to the shoto and specialized crystals.

It looks like the answer to your question is:

**At early levels, use a shoto for mainly defense and blocking, and improve your agressive stance with it by going into the jedi knight PrC as well as the dual wielding feat line.**

Comment: That looks well put together and feeds of other internet resources. I'll wait a while before accepting though.